# Directly access Berkeley database for faster editing/updating than via Gramps?

Tags: gramps

I use [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/) as my prefered genealogy program with Linux and was wondering if it would make sense to access the underlying [Berkeley database](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Database_Formats) directly with a bsddb reader for faster editing or even adding of information than it is possible within Gramps? I imagine something like a [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), see image down below.

Does somebody has had the same idea and experiences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that will be very easy to do because most of the data in the database is stored as serialised python data structures, rather than easily readable fields.

There is [work ongoing](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=GEPS_032:_Database_Backend_API) to add support for additional database backends in the next major release, such as sqlite or postgres, but currently that still stores most of the data as blobs of serialised python data.

There has been talk of going further and breaking the data out so that it is visible directly from the database but I don't think anybody is actually working on that right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer, TomH! As a hypothetical question: if Gramps were to have, let's say, sqlite without blobs and all, would this database convienent to edit from a sqlitebrowser, too?

Comment: I see no reason why not.

Comment: Is there any software available that will do this anyway? In my case I just wanted to bulk remove certain comments, so the underlying structure should remain the same (in theory).