# Direct editing of underlying database for Genealogy program?

Tags: gramps

I like [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/), but dislike it from time to time for its complexity when creating events, notes, person etc., too much tabs and submenus.

I would like to be able to edit the underlying database directly (with something looking like the sqlite browser) but this seems to be an imposible thing since Gramps' database has python code combined with its bsddb database, see [Directly access Berkeley database for faster editing/updating than via Gramps?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9717/directly-access-berkeley-database-for-faster-editing-updating-than-via-gramps)?

Is there any genealogy program which has a complete but easy (eye candy) interface without this submenus and all? Or is there a program which underlying database I can easily edit? Open-source would be nice, but is not a must have.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because it is asking two questions.  I suspect the first one will attract opinion-based answers, so I think you may be better to focus on the second one.  For that, http://sourceforge.net/projects/humo-gen/?source=directory just showed up in a Google search.

Comment: Surely the whole point of using a genealogy program is so that you don't have to fuss with the underlying database of messy tables. There are countless programs that have a much more straightforward interface than Gramps. In fact, I would bet that just about every other genealogy program has a more intuitive interface than Gramps. But they don't tend to have as much functionality or flexibility.

Comment: To me the 'complexity when creating events, person etc.' is a function of having programs which are [person-based rather than record-based](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1471/1006).  Other tools exist for creating notes, which can then be copied-and-pasted into many lineage-based programs, so I don't understand why this is a complex task. (I agree that there are two questions in this question, and don't want to write an answer to the first one here if it will eventually be asked separately.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gramps offers a few options. The first is a Spreadsheet Import/Export. You can export your data as a Spreadsheet (CSV), edit the data, and then import it back in.

Also, Gramps 5.0, due out around June/July will offer different database backends. This in and of itself will not help because even if you use a sqlite database, the data will still be "pickled." However, plans are being made to have individual fields as well.

Comment: Thanks Doug! Why was the database handling created the way it is today?